# Postgres, split single row into multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, unpivot, lateral-join

I've got a table with columns like:

```
+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| age1  | val1 | age2  | val2  | age3  | val3  |
+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 30-40 | 34.5 | 41-50 | 32.01 | 51-60 | 29.13 |
+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to return:

```
+-------+-------+
|  age  |  val  |
+-------+-------+
| 30-40 |  34.5 |
| 41-50 | 32.01 |
| 51-60 | 29.13 |
+-------+-------+
```

I ended out writing a large query using 3 unions like this, but this does not seem right:

```
  select *
  from ( ... ) g1
  union
  select *
  from ( ... ) g2
  union
  select *
  from ( ... ) g3
```

Is there a way to do this without the mess? Seems like I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: "Is there a way to do this without the mess?" Yes, it is called normalize your data.

Comment: The source data is from the CDC, its aggregated into rows in this unfortunate way, we are actually normalizing the data with the very project related to this question, thanks for your helpful (?) input.

Comment: @Belayer rude answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, you can efficiently unpivot the columns to rows with a lateral join:

```
select x.*
from mytable as t
cross join lateral (values 
    (t.age1, t.val1), 
    (t.age2, t.val2), 
    (t.age3, t.val3)
) as x(age, val)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great, learning about lateral joins now.